# Flutter Building layouts

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having trouble on how to build a proper layout like in the picture below, how can i make desgin like this? the code is  **UPDATED** thanks to mr ARVOCI , this is my existing code so far. this the error i receive ***Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'*** and ***Null check operator used on a null value*** what does it mean?

[image]

```
class _HomePageState extends State<transactionLogs> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: double.infinity,
              width: double.infinity,
                      child: Text('Name '),
                    ),
                    Container(
                        height: double.infinity,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                              hintText: 'Search Name'
                          ),
                        )
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: double.infinity,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Text('1'),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: double.infinity,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Text('2'),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: double.infinity,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Text('3'),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: double.infinity,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Text('4'),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: double.infinity,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Text('1'),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: double.infinity,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Text('2'),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: double.infinity,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Text('3'),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: double.infinity,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Text('4'),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ]
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Wrap your Row() in a Column() and then you can add multiple Rows() beneath each other

Comment: just like in my existing code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class _HomePageState extends State<transactionLogs> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Text('Name: '),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        hintText: 'Enter your name'
                    ),
                  )
                )
              ],
            ),
            // Another Row(),
            // Another Row()
          ]
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I received this error Null check operator used on a null value

Comment: @Rene that's not something with this code? Can you share more details?

Comment: i just copy your answer and i receive that error

Comment: Does it say a line number?

Comment: no, but i will post a picture of error i receive

Comment: Wrap the column in a container with size: double.infinity

Comment: `double.infinity`? what?

Comment: height: double.infinity

Comment: Then add a specific height

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap your textField with expanded and some padding to get desired result.

```
return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text('Name '),
                    Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30,15,30,15),
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                              hintText: 'Search Name'
                          ),
                        )
                    )
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Text('1'),
                    Text('2'),
                    Text('3'),
                    Text('4'),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Text('1'),
                    Text('2'),
                    Text('3'),
                    Text('4'),
                  ],
                )
              ]
          )
      ),
    );
```